# Deleted yiiAssets and the entire site throws an CException

Tags: php, yii

While trying to fix a caching issue I accidentally deleted the entire yiiAssets directory (/Website/htdocs/yiiAssets). I recreated the directory, gave it all the correct permissions, but I still get the following error on every page:

> CAssetManager.basePath
>   "/for/bar/baz/Website/src/config/../../htdocs/yiiAssets" is invalid.
>   Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web
>   server process.

I'm unsure how to fix this problem. The site runs on Yii 1.1. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue,

go to

```
protected/runtime/
```

and open all log files in notepad and remove every thing from it and run your application once again.

After this your whole application will rebuild the assets folder automaticaly which ever is required.

And after that all the issues will be rectified.